# R: iterating through unique values of a vector in for loop

Tags: r, loops, iterator

I'm new to R and I am having some trouble iterating through the unique element of a vector. I have a dataframe "School" with 700 different teachers. Each teacher has around 40 students.

I want to be able to loop through each teacher, create a graphs for the mean score of his/her students' over time, save the graphs in a folder and automatically email that folder to that teacher.

I'm just getting started and am having trouble setting up the for-loop. In Stata, I know how to loop through each unique element in a list, but am having trouble doing that in R. Any help would be appreciated.

```
School$Teacher     School$Student    School$ScoreNovember    School$ScoreDec    School$TeacherEmail  
     A                1                35                     45                A@school.org  
     A                2                43                     65                A@school.org    
     B                1                66                     54                B@school.org  
     A                3                97                     99                A@school.org  
     C                1                23                     45                C@school.org
```

Comment: you should show us how the data looks like and what you are trying to achieve. you may not even *need* to use a for-loop, as this is so not R. see the apply() function and its cousins.

Comment: @ichodia could you share a sample of your dataset by pasting the output of `dput(School)`

Comment: @djas  thanks for the comments. I added some sample data, let me know if you need more detail. There are privacy concerns so I'm trying to be careful with the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have 3 questions, which will need separate questions, how do I:

1. Create graphs
2. Automatically email output
3. Compute a subset mean based on group

For the 3rd one, I like using the `plyr` package, other people will recommend `data.table` or `dplyr`packages. You can also use `aggregate` from base. To get a teacher's mean:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(School,.(Teacher),summarise,Nov_m=mean(ScoreNovember))
```

If you want per student per teacher, etc. just add between the columns, like:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(School,.(Teacher,Student),summarise,Nov_m=mean(ScoreNovember))
```

You could do that for each score column (and then chart it) if your data was long rather than wide you could also add the date ('November', 'Dec') as a group in the brackets, or:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(School,.(Teacher,Student),summarise,Nov_m=mean(ScoreNovember),Dec_m=mean(ScoreDec))
```

See if that helps with the 3rd, but look at splitting your questions up too.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems a bit vague and it looks like you want us to write your whole project. Could you share what you have done so far and where exactly you are struggling?

see `?subset`

```
School=data.frame(Teacher=c("A","B"), ScoreNovember=10:11, ScoreDec=13:14)

for (teacher in unique(School$Teacher)) { 
    teacher_df=subset(School, Teacher==teacher)
    MeanScoreNovember=mean(teacher_df$ScoreNovember)
    MeanScoreDec     =mean(teacher_df$ScoreDec)
    # do your plot
    # send your email
}
```

Comment: Thanks RockScience. So the part of subset where you have Teacher==teacher is not working for me. Is there a way to differentiate the fact that 'teacher' is referring to a variable versus just a character string "teacher"?

Comment: read `?subset`. And you need to provide with a sample of the data (or a data in the same format as yours. Otherwise you will likely get code that do not work for you, just because we are using different format of data. (see the comment I put regarding `dput`)